# WindowsからSSHでお名前.comのVPSと接続する時、ホストとSSHキーを連想される方法は？

Tags: windows, ssh

「SSH Permission denied (publickey)」を検索してみれば、解決方法が沢山あるという事は、原因もたくさんあるからでしょう。私の場合は

- ローカルOS：Windows 10
- VPSのOS：Ubuntu 20.04
- プロバイダー：お名前.com
- サービス：VPS（KVM）

プロバイダーという因子は非常に大切です。お名前.comですと、

1. 規定ポートは「10022」です。
2. `ssh root@15X.X.XX.X -p 10022`の様にアカウント名とパスワードだけでは最初からサインインできない様に設定してあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3. 管理画面から個人キーをのダウンロードが提供されています

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

TeraTerm等では接続しやすいですが、TeraTermを使わずに接続する事が必要な時もあります。
質問を聞いた頃、ＳＳＨには詳しくありませんでしたが、論理上ですと、「SSH Permission denied (publickey)」の意味は「15X.X.XX.X:10022というホストと接続するにはどこでキーを取れば良いかわからない」でしょう。そうでしたら、どうやって連想させれば宜しいでしょうか？

ダウンロードされたキーが「C:\Users\User_Name.ssh」ディレクトリにあります。ファイル拡張子は.pemです。ファイル名は、指定可能であるべきでしょう。

追伸

「お名前.com」のサポートに案内してもらう事は無結果でした。

Answer (score 2):

ssh コマンドの `-i` オプションに続けて秘密鍵を指定してください。

**例:**

```
$ ssh -i <秘密鍵のパス>.pem user@host -p 10022
```

Comment: ご回答に感謝致します。ご提案なさった方法と他に、一度だけのキーの指定の上、毎回`-i`で指定せずに接続する方法が御座いますでしょうか？